# IntelliJ don't recognize thymeleaf's variables

Tags: spring-mvc, intellij-idea, thymeleaf

Is it normal for IntelliJ that it doesn't recognize all variables specified in Thymeleaf documentation?

I'm using Thymeleaf engine template in my Spring Boot application project and IntelliJ as IDE but it seems that IntelliJ doesn't implement all THymeleaf features or I have a problem of IDE configuration or I don't understand something.

For example:

```
${param.q}
```

should read `q` variable of `GET` method but IntelliJ doesn't recognize the variable. In running application, it works properly.

Template (param.q is underlined in red)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Title</title>

</head>

<body>

<p th:text="${param.q}">Some text</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Spring Controller

```
package com.drogago.todo.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showIndex2() {
        return "index2";
    }
}
```

Comment: How does the code look like in the editor? I've checked with the sample project and it [looks like this](https://i.imgur.com/C1NrTLr.png). What do you mean by "doesn't recognize"?

Comment: Thank you a lot for the check. So it is a problem of configuration. In my case IntelliJ detect error and underline it in red.

Comment: Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks! I have edited.

Comment: Can you try `$` instead of `#`?

Comment: Sorry, the same result. It is a mistake during writing example. I will look for the problem. Today IntelliJ was updated, but I don't think that it brings the problem.

Comment: Zip and upload the project directory to Dropbox or other file sharing service, the issue is not reproducible with the provided information.

Comment: I have checked it on the laptop where I have not updated IntelliJ and there is no problem in the same project.

Comment: It doesn't help to identify the issue, share the project and [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085). It works for me in 2019.2 release.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I found the solution. There was a problem because of IntelliJ wasn't able to load resources. When in 'Add framework Support' menu was selected Thymeleaf there was information that resources are loading but the process was in an endless loop. I have disabled sync and restart IntelliJ. Then I was closed project in "File" menu and run it again. In the end, I reimport project (in Maven menu). Now it works properly.

Comment: @PawełKubik You can answer your own question on SO, too. Such a solution to an issue can be easier found by future readers. (And as a side effect it increases the chance for upvotes. :)

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. There was a problem because of IntelliJ wasn't able to load resources. When in 'Add framework Support' menu was selected Thymeleaf there was information that resources are loading but the process was in an endless loop. I have disabled sync and restart IntelliJ. Then I was closed project in "File" menu and run it again. In the end, I reimport project (in Maven menu). Now it works properly.